Order of Selichos
In most siddurim used by ashkenazim, nussach Ashkenaz or Sefard, we have a daily addition for selichos sandwitched between tefilas Amidah and Tachnun. Some people suggested to me that it was taken from sefardi siddurim. When comparing the nusach of the daily selichos to the one said on fast days one finds a key difference: in the daily selichos one first makes viduy enumerating the sins: ... אָשַׁמְנוּ, בָּגַדְנוּ, גָּזַלְנוּ, דִּבַּרְנוּ דֹּפִי, and then recites 13 middos shel rachamim, while on the fast days and Yom Kippur katan we do the opposite. A sefardi man told me that in sefardi selichos the viduy always precedes the reciting of 13 middos.
What is a reason why sefardim and ashkenazim have a different order of selichos?

The Sha'arei T'shuva (OC 131:1) mentions the custom of Israel and Sefardi countries (as of early 19th c.) to do the n’filas apayim part of tachanun before V'hu Rachum (cf. Beit Yosef ad loc. in the name of the Gaonim that the reason not to talk between 'amida and n'filas apayim is because it’s an extension of the 'amida, with the 'amida/n'filas apayim complex comprising something like a t’filla arichta). By the same logic, one would assume that the old Sefardi minhag would also have placed any other nusach Ari extras that someone might say (like vidui and 13 midos) after n'filas apayim.
